# How to change selected item's text in a select list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the script below, the "my_theme" element is a select list of a directory listing.

When its "change" event is fired, the jquery is called and triggers a "get" to find out if the selected folder has a style.css file. The get returns true/false.

All that works fine. I'm just trying to determine how to decorate the item in the select list depending on the outcome of the get.

For example, if its false, I want to make the selected item's background gray and append some text to the option name label.

So, if the currently selected item in the list is "alpha", and the $.get returns false, then the text should become "alpha (inactive)".

```
$('#my_theme').change
(
    function() 
    {
    //check if this folder has a style.css file
    $.get('<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/getStyle.php', {theme: myImage}, function(data){doActive(data);});
    }
);

function doActive(data){
if(active){
    //if the stylesheet is missing, append the label with " (inactive)"
    $('#my_theme :selected').text() = $('#my_theme :selected').attr('value') + ' (inactive)';
    }
```

the option's "value" attribute is the same as its label.
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doActive(data){
if(active){
    //if the stylesheet is missing, append the label with " (inactive)"
    $('#my_theme :selected').text($('#my_theme :selected').attr('value') + ' (inactive)');
    }
```

Comment: +1 This works for the text, however, I think I need to test against the "value" of the select and not the text() node (it's persistant and the 2nd time its selected it becomes (inactive) (inactive) , etc.

Comment: Trying to change from using text() to using attr('value'). This doesn't seem to work >     if(!active){$('#my_theme :selected').text($('#my_theme :selected').attr('value') + ' (inactive)');}

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_theme :selected').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html() + ' (inactive)').css('background-color','gray');
});
```

Comment: I can't get an alert inside this function to fire. $('#my_theme :selected').each(function(){alert('in each');}); //Does Not Fire

Comment: Is there an error showing up in the console? (CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome, click Console, refresh the page.)